# Why am I getting [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor on file.close() - error handling

Tags: python, io, ioerror

I have the below code:

version A

```py
try:
    file = open(local_copy, "wt")
    n = file.write(str(soup))
    logging.debug(f'\t{local_copy} saved. {n} lines saved.')
except IOError as e:
    logging.error(traceback.print_exc())
finally:
    file.close()
```

version B

```py
try:
    with open(local_copy, "wt") as file:
        n = file.write(str(soup))
    logging.debug(f'\t{local_copy} saved. {n} lines saved.')
except IOError as e:
    logging.error(traceback.print_exc())
finally:
    None
```

Both are failing with [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor. It is caugt by exception handler higher up the stack.

Now, I am passing `True` (boolean) as local_copy's value. I know it will fail, my goal here however is to handle the error properly.

I ended up doing the below, but do not find this the best solution. I'd like to know why the initial try...catch block cannot catch this. Is there a different, better way to handle `IOErrors`?

```py
if not isinstance(local_copy, str):
    logging.error(f"Cannot store localcopy of the file")
    logging.error(f'"local_copy" variable holds a value of an incorrect type: {type(local_copy)} (required str).')
else:
    try:
        file = open(local_copy, "wt")
        n = file.write(str(soup))
        logging.debug(f'\t{local_copy} saved. {n} lines saved.')
        # with open(local_copy, "wt") as file:
        #     n = file.write(str(soup))
        # 
        # logging.debug(f'\t{local_copy} saved. {n} lines saved.')
    except IOError as e:
        logging.error(traceback.print_exc())
    finally:
        file.close()
        #None
```

OSError also does not catch anything, as well as Exception.

Standalone example:

```
import io

local_copy = True
soup = "Great soup"

try:
    file = open(local_copy, "wt")
    n = file.write(str(soup))
    print(f'\t{local_copy} saved. {n} lines saved.')
except OSError as e:
    print("we got the error")
finally:
    file.close()
print ("Done")
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py 
True saved. 10 lines saved.
Great soupTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print ("Done")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Why am I getting exception ignored?
Also, why the content of soup is being send to stdout?

Comment: Bad file descriptor might happen when you try to close already close file. But as mentioned above - please give more details about your code.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille `IOError` is an alias for `OSError` since Python 3.3

Comment: I have updated the question with standalone, runnable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
local_copy = True
....
file = open(local_copy, "wt")
```

creates a file object from the value `True` which is identical to integer `1`, which represents a file descriptor for the standard output, i.e. the channel where all prints emit the messages by default.

(Usually `open` is used with a filename - I guess you did not intend to write to the standard output.)

When you close that file, you close your standard output. The first print after that point will fail:

```
print("Done")
```

because it cannot print to closed output. This is the cause for the exception reported.

Comment: ok, this answers stdout part of the question - thanks!. still, how to catch first error on file.close(). Just to be clear, I understand the above code fails, I am trying to improve error handling.

Comment: @m0rt1m3r But the `close` does not fail; try a tiny program with just open+close, no print. If you have another question, please describe exactly what the code should do first.

Comment: you're right :/ I have done more debugging on my end and the code was actually failing on the following print statement further down the line (because I closed stdout). I didn't know about descriptor 1, thanks. I will add proper type checking to my code and will throw TypeError exception.